# How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-droid-incredible, ringtone, mp3

I have an HTC Droid Incredible running Android 2.2 FroYo and would like to use custom sounds/songs as ringtones for text message notifications, event and task reminders, Facebook and Twitter notifications, and email messages. I have the MP3s that I want to use located in the /ringtones directory of my phone, but they don't show up on the list of possible sound effects/tones/notifications, but they do show up in the selection for incoming call ringtones. What do I do to use them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put the sounds in the /media/audio/notifications folder on your SD card. Create this folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I had to reboot before it was visible in the selection list

Comment: No reboot necessary using a Moto E (1st gen) on Marshmallow.

Answer (score 8):

I use [Tone Picker](http://www.cyrket.com/p/android/com.hlidskialf.android.tonepicker/) to use any of my mp3 or other audio files for ringtones or other alerts. Even clock alarms!

Pro Tip: ambient music makes for a lousy wake-up call.

Comment: TonePicker was the first ringtone app I could find that didn't want permission to access my contacts.  Perfect!

Answer (score 4):

[RingDroid](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.ringdroid) will let you use any MP3 or part of an MP3 or even record your own sound as an MP3 as a ringtone.

Here's the QR Code:

[image: QR Code for RingDroid]

Comment: RingDroid wants access to my contacts.  Boo RingDroid.

Answer (score 3):

To set up your mp3 file as a ringtone, simply create a new folder on your SD Card and rename it "ringtones", without the quotes of course. (Do same for alarms, notifications and ui). After that, add your mp3 files to the folder. Go to "Setting--sound--phone ringtone", there, you will see your added mp3 file.

Joseph Nwalor (Slow).

Answer (score 2):

It seems in froyo (at least in my HTC Legend with froyo) you need to have the .mp3 file not in  notifications folder but in "ringtones" folder at the same level with notifications.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need to create a folder called "**notifications**" on the root of your SD. You could mount your device to do this or use an application "Astrow" either way, Put your MP3 files here and you can use them as Notification sounds as well as ringtones.

Comment: I added my MP3 files to a notifications directory and they show up as ringtones, but not as notification sounds.

Comment: I know the question is for 2.2, but for the record, it does not work for 2.3.