# Can I add my own notification ring tones from MP3 files?

Tags: notifications, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications)

I've been easily able to add call ringtones but is there a way to add notification ringtones from an MP3?

Answer (score 1):

Go to SETTINGS > SOUND & DISPLAY > NOTIFICATION RINGTONE and choose your ringtone from there.

Note that if you have Handcent SMS, there is a Handcent SELECT MUSIC option that will allow you to select non-system Music / MP3 as the sound.

If you don't use Handcent, there are other ringtone pickers like [Tone Picker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hlidskialf.android.tonepicker) or the excellent [Ringdroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ringdroid).