# Is there a way to have my device say the callers name when the call is coming in?

Tags: calls, htc-desire-z, text-to-speech

I have a HTC Desire Z with Froyo . I am trying to find a way to have my device speak the caller name. I have tried [SayMyName](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.mailboxer.saymyname&feature=search_result) but it only works if you are connected to the internet. I want a similar solution that works even if the device is not connected to the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want it to read the name from your contacts, or the caller ID?

Comment: "Is there an app for X" is generally off-topic here. It's better to ask "is there a way to do X".

Answer (score 3):

[Sanity](https://market.android.com/details?id=cri.sanity&feature=search_result) is another neat app for this.

Alternatively, it is straight forward to configure a Tasker profile to 'say' an alert including the caller's name.

Comment: yes, this would be better, but could you explain in detail how to do the latter....

Comment: I would still recommend sanity. It works like a charm and does a host of other functions too.

Answer (score 2):

You could set each one of your contacts individual ringtones to be a sound file that is just someone saying their name.  It would be pretty tedious, and it wouldn't work for numbers that aren't in your contacts, but at least it's something.

See [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications) on how to set custom .mp3 files as ringtones.