# Ringtones from my MP3

Tags: ringtone

I have in Bluetooth folder some `.mp3` files. How can I make them ringtones? The phone ringtone option doesn't see them.

Answer (score 4):

Add the files to the `/media/audio/ringtones` directory on your SD card.

See also: [How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications)

Comment: That's good. And with the same way for alarmo clock and sms notifcation?

Comment: Indeed. That's the `alarms` and `notifications` sibling directories.

Comment: Hmm, I cant find this directory.  The best I can find is Samsung/music :S

Comment: Are you looking on the external SD card? Your device might not match up with mine.

Comment: Note you may have to reboot your phone to see these changes.

Answer (score 2):

use [Ringdroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ringdroid&feature=search_result)! it's got a spectacular GUI, it automatically finds all music files on your phone, and allows you to make custom ringtones and set them directly from the app. Best ringtone app i've ever used.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .mp3 file in the stock media player, and from there choose Menu>Set as Ringtone.

Comment: And what about alarm clocks and sms notifications?