# I'm having trouble making a custom ringtone

Tags: downloading, ringtone, mp3, google-drive

I have an LG-LS855. I don't seem to have any way to plug it in to my computer. I've made a ringtone I want to use. It's an mp3 file. I've uploaded it onto Google Drive. The only thing I seem to be able to do from my phone is play it.

I've downloaded three apps for custom ringtones. The only one that came close to helping was Tone Picker. It lets me use an mp3 from Google Drive as a ringtone. Or at least, it appears to. The phone still uses its default ringtone.

I've also figured out how to use any of the music on my phone as ringtones, but I can't figure out how to download the mp3 as music either.

Comment: See also: [Add New Ringtones, Notifications and Alarm tones on Nexus One](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20712/16575), [How to manually upload ringtones and notifications to DroidX?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28300/16575), [Ringtones from my mp3](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11376/16575), and many more (simply [search for "ringtones"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=ringtones) or click the "ringtone" tag) :)

Answer (score 1):

answer taken from the question:

> The Dropbox app actually lets you download stuff onto your phone. Once
>   I did that, the phone's ringtone manager let me use it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Ringdroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ringdroid)? Lots of people seem to have success with it.

> Create your own ringtone, alarm, or notification sound from an existing audio file, or record a new one directly on the device.

Comment: I tried it. All it seems to be able to do is mess with audio files that are already in my song list and record stuff. As I already mentioned, I have no trouble using those as ringtones. I just can't figure out a way to move my custom ringtone onto that list.

Comment: @DanielLC Have you tried putting the MP3 file in a local folder in your phone, instead of putting it on Google Drive?

Comment: How? My plan was to upload it to Google Drive on my computer and then download it onto my phone from there. I can't figure out how to download it though.

Comment: @DanielLC Did you download the MP3 file by clicking on it and "Download a copy"?

Comment: I don't have that option. I just have Send, Move to..., Remove offline, Open with, Send link, Rename, and Remove. Open with just plays it.

Comment: @DanielLC Find another way to put it on your phone. Send the MP3 to your GMail, and download it there. Once you have a local copy, try and set it with the apps you've tried. Then, come back and let us know if it worked.