# How to set MP3 ringtone in Android (Nexus S)

Tags: ringtone, google-play-music

I am using [Music](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.music&feature=search_result) (latest up to today) and [TTPOD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.sds.android.ttpod&feature=search_result) as my MP3 players.

After Googling, I suppose I can set my MP3 ring tone, by long press on the song through Music application. However, once I long press, there are only the following selections

- Play
- Add to playlist
- Delete
- Shop for artist
- More by artist
- Search

I was expecting I am able to get a selection choice `Set as ringtone`, but I didn't find one.

May I know what is the "correct" way to set MP3 as ringtone in Android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications)

Comment: Are you doing the long press on the music in the built-in Music app, or in your 3rd party Music app? In the built-in one you should definitely get a "Set As" option when you long-press on an individual tune.

Comment: I am using built-in Music app. They have a new version right now. I get the above options, but not "Set As".

Comment: v3+ of the Music app just doesn't have a `Set As` menu option. You could try uninstalling the updates and using an older version if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't the "correct" way, but IMO it's a good way: use [Ringdroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ringdroid). With it, you can cut a suitable part of the MP3 to be used as a ringtone. This way you can get rid of those pesky intros on songs that have a slow start and save space by not having the entire MP3 duplicate in your ringtones folder.

Comment: It wants to read my contacts. That's too much for only  setting a MP3 from Google Music as ringtone. Is there a better solution after more than 1 year?

Comment: There's another similar app called [Ringtone Maker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.herman.ringtone), but it also requires read/write permissions to contacts because it allows you to set contact-specific ringtones.

Answer (score 4):

In last versions of Android (at least in Nexus S) it's kinda hard to set MP3 as a ringtone. There was an option before in the menus called "Set As" but in the new Music app it disappeared.

What you can do is copy your mp3 to `/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones`,
that `ringtones` folder might be empty or even not exist, in this case just create it.

Then you go to `Settings -> Sound -> Phone ringtone` and select your mp3 from the list.

Good Luck!

Comment: Casey_Miller - thanks! Yours is the only solution that seems to work, and it works perfectly (I have a Nexus S with Android version 2.3.4).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Ringtone Maker](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.herman.ringtone&hl=en), which is a free app.  This app allows you to select a part of your song as the ringtone.  It has some preselected portions (based on popular edits included in the database), or you can select your own portion of the song to set as the ringtone.

If you simply want the beginning of the song as your ringtone, @bakytn's answer is the way to go.

Some other music apps will give you the option to choose a song as a ringtone, such as the $5 [PowerAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.maxmpz.audioplayer&feature=search_result), but I'm not sure what they offer in terms of choosing a portion of the song.

Answer (score -2):

Download MP3 music download app. Select song tab, and press the selected song. You will get option `set as ...`.

Comment: Can you provide a link?