# How can I set a song as a ringtone using the newest version of the Music app?

Tags: updates, ringtone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications)
>   [How to set MP3 ringtone in Android (Nexus S)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-to-set-mp3-ringtone-in-android-nexus-s)

Pressing a track in the Music library no longer offers the option of using that track as a ringtone on the Nexus One after the latest update. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Download [RingDroid](http://market.android.com/details?id=com.ringdroid)