# How can I turn songs from Google Play Music into ringtones?

Tags: google-play-store, ringtone, google-play-music

Is there a way to easily use music from Google Play Music as ringtones on my phone?

Comment: Download the song.. Stock ringtone picker should display it..

Comment: This is probably covered by [How to set MP3 ringtone in Android (Nexus S)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-to-set-mp3-ringtone-in-android-nexus-s), which also refers to Google Music specifically.

Comment: You can only set songs that are actually on your sdcard... music from the cloud on google music are saved in a database, so you can't access them without using root and special apps (or command line sqllite if you're that savvy)

Comment: It's surprising that not more people are interested in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the song and use something like Audacity to edit it. Save to your ringtones directory on your phone. Nothing else out of the ordinary needs to be done.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to edit it with Audacity unless you want to cut it to a specific portion of the song or loop it. There are a bunch of ways to set an unmodified MP3 as a ringtone (as covered in [a previous question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13662/how-to-set-mp3-ringtone-in-android-nexus-s)).

Answer (score 3):

I've got a way to do this that is really simple and doesn't require needing to download to your computer every time. I recommend using the music manager from google play to upload your existing collection of music, first. Otherwise, any track you want to make into a ringtone will need to be purchased first.

From your phone using the chrome browser,  navigate to music.Google.Com. Don't follow the prompt to download the app, instead hit your menu button in the browser and look for the option to "Request desktop site." The music store should load the way you see it when at your computer. Tap next to the name of the track you want, in order to get the three dot menu to come up. If you own it download it, otherwise buy it. Now when you go to find it it'll be in your download folder. This is really just for convenience so you don't have to use your computer at all.

Answer (score 1):

1. download the song on another device
2. use [makeownringtone.com](http://makeownringtone.com/) to cut the ringtone and download it
3. move the ringtone to dropbox
4. open dropbox on your phone and export the ringtone Ringtones or Notifications folder

Comment: Why would you want this done externally (server), when it can be accomplished internally (native, within the device). Plus it involves __more__ work.

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: Most androids sold on the market today come with a ringtone editor/maker already pre-installed on stock ROMs. So even if you had no internet access, you still can "design" your own ringtone.

Comment: I think the problem with that is that Google Play Music is not directly accessible on the phone.

Comment: You don't have to use Play Music, there are other apps that come bundled in the ROM. What do you mean  - not directly accessible? You use a file explorer to locate the songs, then import them in the editing app that the device has and make your ringtone. All localized.

Answer (score 0):

I really like the app [Rings Extended](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.angryredplanet.android.rings_extended). From their Play Store description:

> Replaces the standard ringtone picker with a new one that makes it easy to select from installed music tracks & other sounds. Just go to Settings or an application's settings for a ringtone and you will be prompted to use Rings Extended.

Comment: Please include a link to the app you referenced.