# Oneplus2, define/add user ringtones

Tags: ringtone, oneplus-two

I'm have a OnePlus2 device and I can't seem to set a different ringtone other than those provided with the ROM (Oxygen OS 3.1.0). I can't see an option for it under `Settings > Sound and Notification`.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to set a ringtone without flashing a new Rom or adding some cheap app for it ?

Comment: Have you already checked with our [ringtone tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ringtone/info) and the questions using that tag?

Comment: hi thanks for the tip, an old [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications) gave me a hint

Comment: Glad to read! If it solved your issue: Shall we close your question as duplicate to that? Or is there something to add, so you could write up an answer to your own question?

Comment: it may be a dupe of this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21293/how-can-i-turn-songs-from-google-play-music-into-ringtones, the solution is the same but the questions are different.

Answer (score 2):

As @Izzy hinted to check the tag wiki, I found this old answer

[How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224/how-do-i-set-a-custom-mp3-as-a-ringtone-for-other-notifications)

The answer said I should put the ringtone file at a certain directory in my SD card, that directory doesn't exist in my device but instead I noticed a `ringtones` directory that Hangouts created to insert it's own notification sounds.

I placed an mp3 file in there and now I can set it from `Sound and Notification`.

Comment: "that directory doesn't exist in my device": Simply create it :) See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27740/16575).

Comment: it was already created when hangouts inserted it's audio files there, or at least i think it did

Comment: Yupp – but there's more than one directory (one for ringtones, one for alarms, etc.) :)