# How to use a ringtone downloaded from Google Play store?

Tags: google-play-store, ringtone

I bought a ringtone in the Google Play store. I wanted to make it the ringtone for my phone. It shows as being on my device, but I can not add it as a ringtone. I need to know how I can make this a ringtone on my phone. another song I have says it was added to library but the ringtone doesn't say that. How do I add a song to my library?

Comment: It might help to [edit] your question, adding a link to the downloaded ringtone (I didn't even know Playstore offered those). Also please include where "on your device" the ringtone appears. Coming from the Playstore, that's usually an app: if it had put the ringtone in the right place, it should be found automatically by the system, *as soon as the Media Scanner was run*. If that important part was missed: try rebooting your device and see if you can add it then as ringtone.

Comment: One more hint: In case the reboot doesn't solve it, you might wish to take a look at other [questions tagged "ringtone"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ringtone). Some look as if they might prove helpful for your case.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is possibly covered in : [Set mp3 ringtone in Nexus S](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/14646). In summary, copy the downloaded file to `/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones`, and it'll be available as a ringtone upon next boot. If this doesn't help, another way could be as given [here](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/t5/Samsung-Galaxy-S4/Ringtone-from-google-play-how-do-I-download-and-use-as-ringtone/m-p/1560760#M2590).