# MP3song as ringtone in Android

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, ringtone, lenovo

Can anyone please tell me how to set any one of MP3 songs from Music Library as ringtone for Android phone -Lenovo K4 Note. ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: [How do I set a custom MP3 as a ringtone for other notifications?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/224/16575) / **[Add New Ringtones, Notifications and Alarm tones on Nexus One](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20712/16575)** / [Where is the default ringtone stored?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56905/16575) / **[How to set MP3 ringtone in Android (Nexus S)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13662/16575)** (click the "ringtone" tag below your question for more).

Answer (score 0):

From a PC or Mac (you need the file transfer program for Mac) put the MP3 file into the ringtones folder. The other option is to download a file manager app and move the MP3 into that folder from the device itself.

The ringtones directory is in the root folder, then the sdcard folder.

You will then find the ringtone when you attempt to change it through settings.

Comment: Can we keep a portion of the song as ringtone? . I do not want the whole song.

Comment: You can use a program such as audacity on your PC or Mac to take the MP3 and cut out the piece you want. In addition, quite often you can google a song and find premade ringtones.