# Where is the default ringtone stored?

Tags: ringtone, sony-xperia

I recently brought a *Sony Xperia C.* One of my friends like a few default ringtones of the phone. I tried to search in the internal as well as sd card memory but couldn't find the ringtone.

Where exactly they are stored? Can I send it to my friends using another android phone?

Comment: related http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28300/how-to-manually-upload-ringtones-and-notifications-to-droidx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Default ringtones are usually stored in `/system/media/audio/ringtones`. You might be able to access this location using a file manager.

Keep in mind that, residing on `/system`, this place is read-only at best without root-access: so while you should be able to copy *from* here, you cannot place any files *into* this directory. If you want to manually add ringtones to your device, rather create a similar directory on your SDcard (`/sdcard/media/audio`, with sub-directories for `ringtones`, `alarms`, `notifications`, etc.). This location should be recognized automatically by the Android system.

Comment: I can not locate/system in my data card or memory card, do i need to root the phone to access it?

Comment: You need a file manager that let you do so. Some lock you to the SDCard. You definitly should not need to root for that (though there might be other good reasons, read access to `/system` isn't one of them).

Comment: okay, i got root privilege for my phone, and finally removed all default ringtones & alarms & notifications from `/system` partition.

Comment: `/dscard/media/audio` worked but only after a reboot. Is there a way to avoid rebooting?

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功包卓轩 yes. Triggering the [media scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) by [other means](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media-scanner?sort=frequent) than a reboot.

Comment: On an LG phone, they live in `/product/media/audio/ringtones`

Answer (score 0):

The ringtones are stored under the folder `system > media > audio > ringtones`. You can view the folders using any file manager [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.clean).