# how to get xperia m by default notification tone

Tags: root-access, notifications

I've galaxy grand neo. I like a notification tone of xperia m. So how I will get the tone?
Already I've tried so much to download the notification from web but I didn't get.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `/system/media/audio/ringtones` in your Xperia M and copy the notification tone and place it in `media/audio/ringtones` in SD card in your grand neo phone. Restart the phone. Also refer to Izzy's answer in [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56905/where-is-the-default-ringtone-stored) link