# Where can I find old cyanogenmod notification sounds?

Tags: cyanogenmod, nandroid, themes

I recently had to reflash my phone. And am now missing my old default notification sounds.

I originally flashed CM10 and later upgraded to CM11. Now I wiped the phone and CM11 directly. In this new installation I am missing the notification sounds I used before (namely something like "cm-chime" and "cm-prechime").

How can I get them back?

1. Is there a repository on the internet, where I could download them?
2. Where in the ClockworkMod backup I made before wiping are the notification sounds stored?

Comment: As per this [answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/56905/where-is-the-default-ringtone-stored) by *Izzy*, in the backup, look under `/system/media/audio/ringtones`.

Answer (score 0):

As by the very same answer @Firelord is referring to in his comment on your question, rather look under `/system/media/audio/notifications` :) Well, basically, for all those sounds (ringtones, notifications, alarms, …), simply look below `/system/media/audio/*`.

As the path suggests, those should be in the `system.img` (name may slightly differ, but surely has "system" in it).

To prevent their "disappearance" on future flashes, I'd recommend placing those sounds you wish to keep on your SD card, e.g. below `/sdcard/media/*` (corresponding paths). Android then finds them as well – and a wipe/flash for future Android version installs wouldn't remove them from there (unless you chose to wipe the card – which isn't required for updates).